Having error alert when ./configure curl in a folder with an ".app" extension since macOS 14
I have an Applescript application that launch a webserver that is compiled into it. This webserver is composed of httpd, php, openssl and curl among others. I'm using the --prefix parameter to compile everything where it needs to be.
Until macOS 13, I had no problem with this setup.
Since macOS 14, an error shows up in the Finder during the ./configure of curl : "cannot open the Application My.app as it may be damaged or incomplete"

When this dialog alert appears, the ./configure script is suspended during :
configure:25088: checking whether to enable IPv6
configure:25137: gcc -o conftest -Qunused-arguments -O2 -Wno-pointer-bool-conversion -Werror=partial-availability  -I/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/Webserver/zlib-1.3.1/include -L/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -L/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/Webserver/zlib-1.3.1/lib conftest.c -lz  >&5
configure:25137: $? = 0
configure:25137: ./conftest

This error happens only when compiling inside a folder with an .app extension (which is assumed to be an application by macOS).
If I use the --prefix toward a folder without the .app extension, everything works fine.
I tried the following with the conftest :
otool -L conftest

conftest:
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 2420.0.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.0.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1300.100.9)
        /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/Webserver/zlib-1.3.1/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.3.1)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1345.100.2)

The /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/Webserver/zlib-1.3.1/lib/libz.1.dylib is present and signed for further Apple's notarization.
./conftest in another terminal window has the same result.
Among every sources I compiled, curl is the only one causing me this.
I looked up to what could have changed from macOS 13 to 14 but found nothing.
Thanks for your help.
